# Try to build Azure function app in linux following error returns "No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public"

Tags: c#, linux, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

When I try to build azure functions in Linux(Ubuntu 18.04) Following error returns.
Following are the steps I followed in the process.After cloning the repository from the git.

```
dotnet build
func start --build
```

And following output returns,

```
[5/29/19 6:46:18 AM] No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).
[5/29/19 6:46:18 AM] Host initialized (49ms)
[5/29/19 6:46:18 AM] Host started (55ms)
[5/29/19 6:46:18 AM] Job host started
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /media/ishara/Data/MAS/SAGE/SageShipmentFunctions/SageShipmentFunctionsApp
Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[5/29/19 6:46:23 AM] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000CAE400CD'.
```

Below follows the information about my system,

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.300
 Commit:    73efd5bd87

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.300/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.5
  Commit:  0a3c9209c0

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.300 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.5 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Comment: Have you tried the tips in the error message? make class and method public?

Comment: What repository did you clone?

Comment: Actually this works perfectly, when it was executed from vscode using F5 but not directly from the terminal following same commands...any thoughts? Is there any specific environmental variables to be set up?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of options to try for this kind of error:

- Where are you running 'func start --build' from? 
  Make sure you run it from the folder that has the built artifact, e.g. **`bin\Debug\net461`**.
- If you are converting from another project or version.

In the VS csproj file, make sure AzureFunctionsVersion is present

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
...etc
```

- You should upgrade to the latest Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions if it is not, sometimes code repo in the sample have the lower version.

Try these and see if it works, if not please provide the code repo link will take it forward.